# Вывод массива jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть следующий массив:

```
let names = [
    ['Peavy', 'Wagner', 4],
    ['Stefan', 'Weber', 2],
    ['Jean', 'Bormann', 3]
]
```

Нужно, чтобы всё это выводилось в цикле через блок `item` следующим образом:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="name1">Peavy</div>
        <div class="name2">Wagner</div>
        <div class="code">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="name1">Stefan</div>
        <div class="name2">Weber</div>
        <div class="code">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="name1">Jean</div>
        <div class="name2">Bormann</div>
        <div class="code">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Перелопатил уйму вариантов, ничего не выходит. Как добиться такого вывода?

Например, вот это работает, но только для последнего элемента:

```
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    $('.item').each(function() {
        $('.name1').text(names[i][0]);
        $('.name2').text(names[i][1])
        $('.code').text(names[i][2]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На чистом JS можно сделать следующим способом:

1. Пробежимся по массиву `names` с помощью метода `forEach`.
2. Добавим к `innerHTML` нашего `.list` нужную разметку.

(Я бы рекомендовал заменить `div.list` на `ul` и `div.item` на `li`.)

```js
const list = document.querySelector(".list")

const names = [
  ['Peavy', 'Wagner', 4],
  ['Stefan', 'Weber', 2],
  ['Jean', 'Bormann', 3]
];

names.forEach(([name1, name2, code]) =>
{
  list.innerHTML += `
     <div class="item">
        <div class="name1">${ name1 }</div>
        <div class="name2">${ name2 }</div>
        <div class="code">${ code }</div>
    </div>
  `;
})
```

```css
.item { margin: 16px 0; }
```

```html
<div class="list"></div>
```